Allow insecured content - deprecated, what is the workaround now
I have a web application which loads cctv stream using websockets. it was served as ws: without ssl certificated. I used chrome option in site setting to allow insecure content and it was working. suddenly it started to fail and it says the option to allow mixed content in deprecated. what is the workaround for this. this will be big issue to many teams around the world that to convert ws: to wss: will take longer to do the needed changes.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://xxxx:5200/'. This endpoint should be available via WSS. Insecure access is deprecated.
Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated.

"... this will be big issue to many teams around the world" - probably only for these who did not understand what "deprecated" means, i.e. that it will still be allowed for a while when explicitly enabled but will be removed eventually. So there was actually lots of time to adapt the code.  Also, in professional code one does not expect users to fiddle with browser settings in order to use deprecated features, this should be done for testing or private use only.

what is the workaround for this Umm, do your job in the first place? That mixed content is insecure has been known for decades, and Google warned you Chrome was going to stop allowing it at least five years ago.
